# OCR Space response ParsedResults[0] error

Tags: python, api, rest, flask, ocr

I am making a program in python that scans receipts and relies on an OCR response using the OCRSpace API. It has worked perfectly in that past with a couple hundred tries but when uploading an image to my flask server from an iphone instead of a computer, the image's contents do not have an OCR result. I have tried using the same image on their website and it gives a normal response but with my flask app it returns

```
parsed_results = result.get("ParsedResults")[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I am using the code:

```
img = cv2.imread(file_path)

                height, width, _ = img.shape
                roi = img[0: height, 0: width]
                _, compressedimage = cv2.imencode(".jpg", roi, [1, 90])
                file_bytes = io.BytesIO(compressedimage)
                url_api = "https://api.ocr.space/parse/image"
                result = requests.post(url_api,
                                files = {os.path.join(r'PATH', file_name): file_bytes},
                                data = {"apikey": "KEY",
                                        "language": "eng",
                                        #"OCREngine": 2,
                                        "isTable": True})
                result = result.content.decode()
                result = json.loads(result)
                parsed_results = result.get("ParsedResults")[0]
                global OCRText
                OCRText = parsed_results.get("ParsedText")
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> iPhones and iPads as of iOS 11 use HEIF as standard; there are no incompatibilities when transferring to PC or sending e.g. by sharing, as the images are converted to the widely supported JPEG format; however, incompatibilities arise when using cloud services e.g. Google Photos.

[High Efficiency Image File Format (HEIF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format)

Comment: Just an idea ;)

Comment: The program is having an issue with a particular set of images that were taken on the iphone. The program has no issues with photos that were taken on computer and sent to the iphone. Does it make a difference if the photo is originally taken on an iphone?

Answer (score 0):

As @rob247 posted IPhones are using HEIF format by default(official link [here](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT207022))
So when you uploaded photos to the script please try converting it to JPEG before use since opencv does not support *heif,*avif,*heic yet see issue [#14534](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14534) also view the list of supported formats at opencv [imread](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html) if you prefer other formats

Comment: @Python 123 please try conversion to JPEG and let me know the result